# Scala: convert a return type into a custom trait

Tags: scala, implicit, implicit-conversion, implicit-typing

I've written a custom trait which extends Iterator[A] and I'd like to be able to use the methods I've written on an Iterator[A] which is returned from another method.  Is this possible?

```
trait Increment[+A] extends Iterator[A]{
    def foo() = "something"
}

class Bar( source:BufferedSource){
    //this ain't working
    def getContents():Increment[+A] = source getLines
}
```

I'm still trying to get my head around the whole implicits thing and not having much like writing a method in the `Bar` object definition.  How would I go about wrapping such an item to work in the way I'd like above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.  Took me a few tries to understand:

```
object Increment{
    implicit def convert( input:Iterator[String] ) = new Increment{
        def next() = input next
        def hasNext() = input hasNext
    }
}
```

and I'm done.  So amazingly short.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible without playing tricks. A mixin inheritance happens at compile time, when it can be type-checked statically, and it is always targeted at another class, trait, etc. Here you try to tack a trait on an existing object "on the fly" at runtime.

There are workarounds like implicit conversions, or maybe proxies. Probably the "cleanest" way would be to make Increment a wrapper class delegating to an underlying Iterator. Depending on your use case there might be other solutions.

Comment: I feel that there has got to be an implicit conversion that will solve the trick.  However, the solution continues to elude me.